# Selenium with Firefox not working. browser turns red and closes

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

Not seeing a similar issue anywhere else, but what happens is when i run my code. The webpage i want opens but immediately after my browser turns red and the page closes. This only happens with webdriver and selenium not requests. Geckodriver is what Firefox uses. Pretty sure Gecko installed correctly and it is inside my PATH. Before it wasn't doing anything at all. So i dont think that is the current issue. Again been googling around and i don't see anyone else having their browser turn red.  I wonder if its just a file name i need to change but idk what file that would be..

Here is my code:
'''

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re




driver = webdriver.Firefox()

r = driver.get('https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/')

soup = bs(r, 'html').content

print(r.content)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have downloaded the latest gekodriver:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

and pass it to driver as :

```
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="pathtogeko/gekodriver.exe")
```

This will ensure you are using the correct gekodriver.